# Ao mapear classe para viewModel, alguns dados são perdidos

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, automapper

Tenho uma consulta que retorna um cliente e seu telefone, mas ao mapear a classe para a *viewModel*, eu perco os dados de telefone:

consulta:

```
public Cliente ObterClientePorId(Guid ClienteId)
{
      var consulta =
            Contexto.Cliente.Join(Contexto.Telefone,
                                  p => p.ClienteId, 
                                  pt => pt.ClienteId,
                                 (p, pt) => new {p, pt}).FirstOrDefault();

  if (consulta != null)
  {
      var cliente = consulta.p;
      cliente.telefone = consulta.pt;

      return cliente;
 }
```

Mas ao fazer o mapeamento da classe cliente para a *viewModel* `cliente`, ele perde os dados que estavam em `telefone`.

Mapeamento:

```
    public ClienteViewModel ObterClientePorId(Guid ClienteId)
    {
        //aqui tem os dados de telefone
        var consulta = _cliente.ObterClientePorId(ClienteId);
        //aqui o telefone fica null
        var cliente = Mapper.Map<Cliente, ClienteViewModel>(consulta);

        return cliente;
    }
```

`ClienteViewModel`:

```
public class ClienteViewModel
{
    public ClienteViewModel()
    {
        ClienteId = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    // campos...

    public List<TelefoneViewModel> TelefoneViewModel { get; set; }

    //mais campos...
}
```

Comment: Já tentou não usar o Automapper?

Comment: não tentei, ai eu faria o mapeamento na mão?

Comment: Sim, usando operadores implícitos, por exemplo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tentou mapear a classe Telefone para "TelefoneViewModel"? Falo isso pois sua classe ClienteViewModel possui uma List< TelefoneViewModel> e não List< Telefone>.

Talvez isso funcione:

```
var telefones = Mapper.Map<List<Telefone>, List<TelefoneViewModel>>(consulta.telefone);
var cliente = Mapper.Map<Cliente, ClienteViewModel>(consulta);
cliente.TelefoneViewModel = telefones;
```

Se não funcionar, compartilhe suas classes Cliente e Telefone, por favor.

Abraços.

Comment: deste modo funcionou, obrigado! Eu tinha tentado fazer algo parecido, só não tinha feito aquele cast pra list.

Comment: @austin felipe Como ficaria caso a consulta retornasse uma lista de lientes, como faria para mapear esses telefones?

Comment: @AlexandrePreviatti Não entendi a pergunta direito. Se retornar uma lista de clientes, não precisa de Cast, certo?

Comment: @AustinFelipe como é retornado apenas um cliente, eu consigo recuperar os telefones com "consulta.telefone" se fosse uma lista de clientes não seria possível... A dúvida é, se em vez de:  var cliente = Mapper.Map<Cliente, ClienteViewModel>(consulta); fosse var cliente = Mapper.Map<List<Cliente>, List<ClienteViewModel>>(consulta); supondo que a consulta fosse uma lista de clientes, como faria esse mapeamento dos telefones?

Comment: @AlexandrePreviatti Entendi. Da para você colocar as ações de mapear dentro de um foreach, ou seja, você pega uma lista de clientes, faz o foreach na lista e faz o mesmo processo ai da resposta.